# Right click menu highlight in windows 10

Tags: menu, kernel, highlight, right-click

I am very new to programming. I am starting to learn Python. I think it was a Coursera tutorial that recommended I install Visual Studio Code. So I installed it, typed print("Hello World"), and ran it.

VSC wanted to install some kernel thing. I figured I had to accept. Now when I mouse-over in right-click menus in Windows there is no (grey) highlight. I tried rebooting and uninstalling VSC to no avail.

Do you know how I can fix this? Thanx for any help.